# Determine if Web-To-Lead or API Created A Lead?

Tags: api, leads, web2lead, developer, website-integration

We have 94% of our lead forms using a custom-programmed "Funnel" for processing our leads.

However, in the Dark Ages when the company was using Web-to-Lead, some of those pages still exist (non-API, using only web-to-lead, which is "secured", haha, by knowing the OrgID).

Long story short:

How can I determine if **a Lead came from Web-to-Lead, versus API, versus even just being typed into Salesforce?**  I see no evidence that this exists, unless we had the foresight to put a variable into our API "funnel" that ONLY the Funnel stamped (and no one "discovered" later), plus that doesn't give me people who were entered via the SF GUI itself.

*I haven't even thought about web-to-lead (seriously) in over two years, and just today (re-)realized that it's literally JUST THE OID that is needed for ANYONE to insert into our Org.*
Thanks.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_leads_what_status_is.htm. I imagine it's not too helpful 2 years later... Anything interesting in CreatedBy? Or field history? P.S. So what's your org id? ;)

Comment: My Org ID is "0123YourFunnyABC"  (wait I think I'm missing a character)  ;)   As for your LINK, very interesting.  I'm going to play with that to see if it is the solution.   Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully Person Accounts don't screw this up (considering it's Lead, I would assume/hope not).

Comment: Lead Status "default" value is set in all cases, so no help there.  Unread By Owner is a no go as well.   Thanks for trying, @eyescream   ;)

Comment: There is a lead source and if by any means for web to lead they set source as Lead you should be good else its difficult

Comment: Lead Source is stamped in 99.9% of cases (web2lead, API, etc).  :-/  I may be out of luck.  Unless of course someone finds something magical.  Ultimately our WebDev team will have the time to migrate all pre-existing Web2Lead forms to our Funnel, which solves the problem.

The fact that someone can just copy a web2lead form, and start injecting records into your Org... is bizarre.  :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so there are a couple of tricks you can do.

Background: you can include custom fields in your web to lead, and use css/html to hide them and or pre populate the data.

so, with that in mind, I like to do the following.

Put the form on the page, with an unpopulated, hidden field called "Web2lead__c" or some such. 
Strip out the OrgID from the form.

Write a javascript function that populates the form's oid and web2lead__c fields either on the dom's load completion event or on the form's submit button being clicked.

This cuts down on spam, and helps you pre-funnel things by origin.

Comment: This is fine... if we are to go back, grep all the pages using web2lead, and update them.   But, if we do that, we're going to take the extra time and simply update them from web2lead to use our Funnel (SF API) instead.  This is an attempt to at least detect that something came from web2lead "out of the box".   :-/   But thanks.

Comment: Web2Lead WILL DISAPPEAR from our sites eventually.  It only hasn't so far due to limited personnel versus time available for ongoing projects.   :-P

Comment: I don't know now.  We may go ahead with something like this (start as of "today" marking all of our FUNNEL/API insertions with an extra hidden marker, so that "new inserts" are at least marked (API) or not marked (web2lead or SF GUI).... hmm.

Comment: We ended up (since we have a "CPU" for all webform submissions) simply adding the "Created by API" checkbox to our Leads and autosetting it in our "CPU".  Thanks for the input.  ;)   Did I mention that web2lead is evil?   (hahahaha)  Perhaps if it had ANY security whatsoever... :-P  Thank God for the API.